# Calcular edad a partir de una fecha de nacimiento

Tags: sql, oracle, mysql-workbench

Quiero crear una función que permita calcular la edad de una persona
utilizando como parámetro una fecha de nacimiento que se pueda
encontrar disponible en una tabla.

El cálculo que está haciendo la función lo dejo como ejemplo en el siguiente SELECT:

```
SELECT 
TRUNCATE((DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, STR_TO_DATE(Fecha_nac, '%Y-%m-%d'))/365.25),0) AS Edad 
FROM Paciente;
```

Comment: Hola Marcelo_p, te damos la bienvenida al sitio. Por favor, completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre la comunidad y el funcionamiento general de SOes (y de esa manera conseguirás tu primera medalla en el sitio). La pregunta tiene las etiquetas de Oracle y MySQL, ¿qué base de datos estás usando? También, por favor incluye el error que te aparece al ejecutar ese comando.

Comment: Como nota aparte (aunque me imagino que seguramente sea la causa)... parece que estás usando `TRUNCATE` para quedarte con una subcadena, pero truncate lo que hace es borrar el contenido y no truncar texto (para lo que necesitarias LEFT, RIGHT, o SUBSTR si no recuerdo mal). Al ejecutar el comando que compartes, te tiene que dar un error en la base de datos. Por favor, indícanos cuál es.

Comment: Dividir entre 365.25 no es una buena opción para calcular la edad. Tendrás múltiples errores en especial cerca de la fecha de cumpleaños.

Answer (score 0):

```html
CREATE FUNCTION CalcularEdad(@fecha_nacimiento DATE)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @edad INT
    SET @edad = DATEDIFF(YEAR, @fecha_nacimiento, GETDATE())
    RETURN @edad
END;
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).